# Android data storage

Tags: android

Hi
 in my application i have temporary data , currently am using application context for saving these data, but the problem comes when my app put in to background, i loss the data and my application crashing. any way to solve this problem. With the normal flow i don't get any problem, these problem comes when my app put in to background for long time,when resumes app crashing.

Comment: Application is put in the background using Home key (not Back key)? Can you please paste your eror log, without it it is hard to say anything more precisely. Have you taken into acount useful suggestion from the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to persist your data when it's paused and repopulate your data when you resume your application.

You might want to take a look at the [Component Lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles) section of the Android documentation to figure out what would work best for your app.